# Using array.map, promises, and setTimeout to update an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, settimeout

I am looking to iterate through an array of users *(with only the id property set)*, call an endpoint every two seconds with each id, and store the associated user's name from the response into an updated array.

*e.g. update* `[{ id: 1 }]` *to* `[{ id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham" }]`

Here is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const users = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

function addNameToUser(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${user.id}`)
      .then(response => {
        user.name = response.data.name
        resolve(user);
      });
  })
}

const requests = users.map((user, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return addNameToUser(user);
  }, index * 2000);
});

Promise.all(requests).then((updatedArr) => {
  console.log(updatedArr);
});
```

Everything works great without the `setTimeout`, but it's important that I only send a request every two seconds. So for three users, I would like to see the result from my `Promise.all` log after six seconds or so.

**Worth noting:** This is not the actual problem I am working on, but the easiest example I could come up with to help highlight the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Your mean  is requests  user1 and wait 2 seconds, requests  user1 and wait 2 seconds, ...
Or request user1 ended and wait 2 seconds, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand, the core of your question is how to space your processing by 2 seconds apart, right?

```js
const users = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

/* throttledProcess is a function that does your processing spaced by the given interval millisecond */
const throttledProcess = (items, interval) => {  
  if (items.length == 0) { // stop when there's no more items to process
    console.log('ALL DONE')
    return
  }  
  console.log('PROCESSING', items[0], Date()) // this is where your http call/update/etc takes place
  setTimeout(() => throttledProcess(items.slice(1), interval), // wrap in an arrow function to defer evaluation
    interval)
}

throttledProcess(users, 2000) // run process. shows output every 2 seconds
```

Run this code and every 2 secs, it will log out which user is being processed.

Hope this helps.
Cheers,

Answer (score 6):

You need to return a Promise from the map's callback. Since this promise will be resolved by the `setTimeout()`, we'll use the [Promise constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

The resolved timeout promise should return the Axios promise, which will return the result when resolved.

Note: since Axios returns a Promise, we don't need to wrap it with another Promise constructor. See [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) question and answers.

```js
const users = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

const addNameToUser = (user) => 
  axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${user.id}`)
  .then(({ data }) => ({
    ...user,
    name: data.name
  }));

const requests = users.map((user, index) =>
  new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(() => resolve(addNameToUser(user)), index * 2000)
  ));

Promise.all(requests).then((updatedArr) => {
  console.log(updatedArr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```